# Is anchor tags between pages deprecated?

Tags: html, anchor

I'm doing a page that needs to work without JavaScript and in one scenario I need to link to a page and "scroll" (read start at) the browser to an anchor tag. The link looks like this

```
http://www.mypage.com?param=1#anchor
```

The anchor is implemented like

```
<div id="anchor"></div>
```

I have tested this in Microsoft edge, Chrome and IE 11 but none of them supports this. The browser starts at the top like no anchor exists.

Am I doing something wrong, has it never been supported or is it deprecated? I can't find that much out there.

Comment: Your code is probably wrong. Post it here.

Comment: have you tried `http://www.mypage.com/#anchor?param=1` (putting the anchor before the url parameter)?

Comment: I read on SuperUser that you should put the anchor last http://superuser.com/questions/498617/does-an-anchor-tag-come-before-the-query-string-or-after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an anchor tag:

```
<div id="anchor"></div>
```

It's a `div` tag.  This is an [anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

```
<a id="anchor"></a>
```

Comment: `<a name="anchor"></a>` is the old anchor tag, id on divs should work, too

Comment: Id and name should both work (albeit not all elements have a name attribute), with id having precedence. See answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id

Comment: This answer actually works! I don't like having an a-element, I'd rather have it on the div, but I guess this will have to do :)

Comment: Note that anchors don't seem to be fully supported. A URL that includes "#NAME" at the end which is input by a user in the address bar or by clicking a link is not sent to the remote server in the GET request. Instead, apparently, the browser then scrolls the GET output to the anchor using the saved anchor name. This means that server-side processing cannot obtain the full requested URL, including the anchor name, which appears to be a very bad design.

Comment: @DavidSpector: That is behavior by design, and it's always worked that way.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL  The server has no need for the fragment identifier, and the browser uses it to display the specified anchor.  The "very bad design" as you call it is exactly what an anchor is and does.  It's "fully supported" because the behavior you've observed is exactly the behavior that's intended.  Though you're certainly welcome to propose changes to the standards if you like: https://www.w3.org/participate/