# Anchor tag drops to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a problem with my anchor tag from a separate page to the designated page, loading then bumping to the bottom of the page. Is there a fix for this? See link for complete code.

jQuery

```
 <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var allPanels = jQuery('.accordion > dd').hide();

  jQuery('.accordion > dt > a').click(function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault(); // don't use return false;
  allPanels.slideUp('normal');
  jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown('normal');
  });

  jQuery(location.hash).show();

});
</script>
```

http://jsbin.com/cugagoruni/edit?html,css,js,output

http://demo.xhalocigsx.com/points/#reviewpoints

Comment: Does the JSbin example demonstrate the problem? I don't see it.

Comment: And what's your anchor's `href` attribute value?

Comment: @isherwood I can provide a link http://demo.xhalocigsx.com/points/#reviewpoints

Comment: Named anchors are a somewhat defunct technique and can cause location problems. Try using ID values on the anchor (or a parent element) instead.

Comment: a href="/points/#reviewpoints">Points</a>

Comment: It scrolls correctly in Pale Moon, but your menu gets over it. You will have to use some js code to scroll to correct position.

Comment: I have <a name="#reviewpoints">Writing Product Reviews</a> on the last accordion tab

Comment: I tried changing the position of the anchor and it still hit  the bottom.

Comment: Is there a way to control where the anchor hits? like centering the item being anchored in the browser?

Comment: Sure, but that's beyond the scope of this question. It involves `offset()`.

Comment: Would you mind showing me where I would place offset? Or would I have to add another section to the script?

Comment: There are other libraries being used and controlled. The live version of this site is a very complex magento build.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the target page is yours, try changing this

```
<dt>
    <a name="#reviewpoints">Writing Product Reviews</a>...
</dt>
```

to this

```
<dt id="reviewpoints">
    <a href="#">Writing Product Reviews</a>...
</dt>
```

Named anchors are known to cause position problems, and in HTML5 there is no `name` attribute for anchors anyway. Also, the `href` attribute is required.

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)

In addition, you seem to have jQuery issues on the page:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function

This usually means that either jQuery isn't available or you have an alias conflict with another library.

Update: You appear to be loading at least 3 versions  of jQuery in that page. Are they being handled properly?

Comment: Okay I see what you mean, there is an issue with that. The <dd> doesnt open when I land on the page anymore with that line of code changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just try using **[slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)**:

```
$(function() {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion>dd');
    allPanels.hide();
    $('.accordion>dt>a').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        el=$(this).parent().next();
        allPanels.not(el).slideUp();
        el.slideToggle();
    });
    $(location.hash).show();
});
```

Comment: The anchored accordion tab is supposed to open up as well with the script im using.

Comment: It will, but you must fix your elements ID.
I saw two id reviewpoints on your page. fix it and than you can use   $(location.hash).show();
or
$(location.hash).click();
in the code I posted, dipends of what you want to use, if the DIV or the A element

Comment: You posted my code in a meta tag??? Ok, please, place it in a script tag at the bottom of your page, just before the </body> tag. :/

Comment: I added your script. and removed the ID's. I added an A name=reviewpoints

Comment: its in a script tag on the actual static block(page)

Comment: Now it just needs a small adjustment.... like an offset to the top about 200 pixels

Comment: no, it's not I'm looking at your code through the console... and you have`<meta property="og:description" content="
$(function() {
var allPanels = $('.accordion>dd');
`

Comment: Jason please, trust me, you must delete the code I've done, put it between a `<script>
$(function() {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion>dd');
    allPanels.hide();
    $('.accordion>dt>a').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        el=$(this).parent().next();
        allPanels.not(el).slideUp();
        el.slideToggle();
    });
    $(location.hash).show();
});
</script>`
and place it on your page.