# creating a link to a div

Tags: html, e-commerce, anchor, href, ria

is it possible to create a link to a div? this is my line of code:

```
     output +='<h2><a href=\"link-to-a-website" >' + val.product + '</h2>';
```

I have created a rich internet application and I need this to link to a div within my website

Comment: You can link using an ID. Given `<div id="foo">...`, link using `<a href="product#foo">foo</a>`
Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but you need to use `ID` instead of `CLASS`.

Example:

```
<h2><a href="#targetDiv" >' + val.product + '</a></h2>

<div id="topDiv">
</div>
<div id="targetDiv">
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/45o6u4Le/2/

---

The target div could be on a different page/site too but you will have to specify the path correctly.