# HTML anchor in URL is not working in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, anchor

I've been pulling my hair on a tiny thing: https://numa.co/about/#corporate-innovation

This URL doesn't go to the right anchor, **only in Chrome** and I can't see why... It works in our development environment. The only difference I can see is that we're behind [Cloudflare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloudflare) in production and it's HTTPS. I can't see how this would make a difference though.

Comment: One thing you may want to try is cleaning up the HTML errors https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fnuma.co%2Fabout%2F

Comment: it's working fine in mine.

Comment: @KaushalSuthar Chrome on Mac ? All of my coworkers have the same issue than me

Comment: Chrome on PC. Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

This is a workaround to your problem and works fine in all major browsers.

Put this JavaScript code in head section of the page where your anchor is.

```js
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    if(window.location.hash) {
       elmnt = document.getElementById(window.location.hash.substring(1));
           elmnt.scrollIntoView(true);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting is off. Shouldn't the script tags be left out?

Comment: Looks highlighted to me..

Answer (score 1):

You have two elements with the same `id="corporate-innovation"`. The browser is going to the first of those elements. `id`'s must be unique to one element. [Check the spec.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: Re *"The browser is going to the first of those elements"*: Isn't that implementation-dependent?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the a name is empty to me. This needs to be the same as the URL fragment. Take a look at this view of my inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9JD3.jpg

You might need to take a look at the original HTML to see if there's an issue with syntax. The inspector on the image is Chrome on Mac.

I would try to change the HTML to be more like this:

```
<a name="corporate-innovation"></a>
<h3 style="color:#E50064">Corporate Innovation</h3>
<span style="color:#E50064"><p>NUMA helps corporates innovate in a different way by collaborating with an ecosystem of entrepreneurs and experts. We provide new methodology training, accelerated intrapreneurship projects, and create open innovation programs for large companies and public institutions.</p>
</span>
```

Comment: I've put that just as a test, I'm falling back to the <h3 id="corporate-innovation"> because it's the regular html5 way if you don't need an anchor (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)

But it really looks like there's something extra that is happening on chrome on mac, that should be very straightforward

Comment: Yeah i thought it looked a little bit like there was a missing " somewhere and Chrome was trying to compensate for it somehow!