# Passing data-target along with redirect to in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a show page which has 3 tabs. The third tab has a add new action and when the item is created the page redirects to the first tab by default . How can i pass the id of the third tab in the redirect path of the create action?

i.e redirect_to manufacturer_path(@item.manufacturer.id) redirects to third tab in manufacturer show page

Comment: redirect_to some_path(:format => "divId"), i think this u need to call up div from url

Comment: But, the url doesnt have the id . U just switch between the tabs in the show page

Comment: i think u need to assign ids to those tabs and need to pass extra param from redirect to eg. manufacturer_path(@item.manufacturer.id, :manufacturer => true)  and write jquery (to show / hide divs ) under if params[:manufacturer] ...

Comment: could you tell me what the :manufacturer => true does here?

Comment: it's just extra param so on show page if you received that param on page u can add javascript on that page below condition like <% if params[:manufactuer]%> <javascript> show / hide divs  </javascript> <% end %>

Comment: hey the  divs are showing correctly.. i just want the page to go a particular when it is redirected after create

Answer (score 1):

Use redirection to anchor:

```
redirect_to manufacturer_path(@item.manufacturer.id), anchor: "tab3"
```

**BUT** it seems that browser will not act scrolling to it, so, also you have to just render a proper part of view also claused in `if` condition.

The anchor will be searched by a browser in case for `id="tab3"` followed by `name="tab3"`. See [the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/484781/446267).

Comment: what is anchor ? is the tab3 the id?

Comment: @PallaviHegde So, it will look for id="tab3" followed by name="tab3"

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ   but if "id" is hidden can it be showed just calling from url?

Comment: @chaitanya but you are able to show it in a view during rendering of the redirect.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ got it

Comment: @PallaviHegde what did you do?

Comment: passed the id it should be redirected along with the anchor

Comment: @PallaviHegde yes but anchor is passed to action when redirected, just read the anchor name and render proper data