# Jump Links with HAML on a RoR website

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, anchor, haml

Super simple question here, yet I can't seem to find a definitive answer.

I'm currently working a page where a list of links will lead to different areas of the page. I know how to do this is regular HTML (with the "name" field) but I'm not sure how to do it in HAML. I only started working with it a short time ago. I tried doing it like this, which isn't working.

```
.li 
   = link_to 'Information', '#info'
```

The section I'm trying to link down to:

```
.h2 INFORMATION { name: 'info' }
```

There's a weird scarcity of info regarding how to solve this? If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than this:

```
.h2 INFORMATION { name: 'info' }
```

you want this:

```
.h2{name: 'info' } INFORMATION
```

The attribute hash needs to be right next to the class name. This generates:

```html
<div class='h2' name='info'>INFORMATION</div>
```

with the `name` attribute. In your code the `{ name: 'info' }` is just included as part of the content of the div.

Answer (score 1):

The [`link_to` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) can produce links with anchors:

```
link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, anchor: "wall")
# => <a href="/profiles/1#wall">Comment wall</a>
```

```haml
.block
  %h2#block1 Block 1
  = link_to "Block 2", route_path(anchor: "#block2")
.block
  %h2#block2 Block 2
  = link_to "Block 1", route_path(anchor: "#block1")
```

**As a side note**: I would recommend using the `id` attribute instead of the `name` attribute on your headings/sections. A lengthy discussion and answer as to why can be found in this thread: [HTML anchors with `name` or `id`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)

Comment: Thank you, next time I think I will use "id" instead of "name", it was messing up my code a bit.

Comment: You are welcome. Could you accept one of the answers? :)

Comment: @Leia_Organa, would you mind accepting my answer if that fixed the issue then? Thanks :)