# How to render view to open at anchor id

Tags: twig

Does anyone know if it's possible to render a view to open at an anchor tag in the middle of a page?

I want `index.html` to open at `id="xyz"`.

This is my Controller code:

```
View::renderTemplate('Folder/index.html', [
        'array' => $array
    ]);
```

This throws an error:

```
View::renderTemplate('Folder/index.html#xyz', [
        'array' => $array
    ]);
```

Comment: This nothing to do with `twig`, you just need specify the `id`xyz on the element you want your browser to scroll to. Some extra information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks. I just figured that out. I appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, but you can use this solution with javascript.

Add the anchor on the page with the twig template.
If the javascript find the ID, it redirects the nativator to the anchor without reloading the page.

```
{% block body %}
   <h2 id="goTo">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            if(document.getElementById("goTo")){
                location.href = "#goTo"
            }
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

If you want redirect with an HTTP 301/302 code and anchor you can see _fragment https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-routing-improvements