# Anchors nor ID work to reference a specific section on a page

Tags: html, anchor

I've been trying to use anchor tags and ID's to reference specific sections within a page but for some reason all I get back is a blank page. No matter how many different configurations I try, the most I get to work is just one link, and then the second displays just a blank page.

Been trying `<a href>`, `<a name>` and using the `<div ID="">` but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Here's the link and section code:

```
<li>
  <a href="servicios.html#distro">Distribución del espacio</a>
</li>

<section id="distro" class="section-block replicable-content bkg-charcoal color-white no-padding-bottom">
  <div class="row horizon" data-animate-in="preset:slideInRightShort;duration:1000ms;" data-threshold="0.3">
    <div class="column width-5 offset-2">
      <h2 class="mb-30"><a name="#distro">Distribución del espacio</a></h2>
    </div>
  ...
```

[See website here](http://www.hermanmillercatalogo.com/servicios.html)

Check the menu option under "Servicios"

BTW Also been using href instead of name in the anchor to no avail.

Comment: More code, please. The section you are trying to access and the links to those sections, not just blank tags.

Comment: Here's the menu code: `<li><a href="servicios.html#distro">Distribución del espacio</a></li>` and here's the section: `<section id="distro" class="section-block replicable-content bkg-charcoal color-white no-padding-bottom">
<div class="row horizon" data-animate-in="preset:slideInRightShort;duration:1000ms;" data-threshold="0.3">
      <div class="column width-5 offset-2">
       <h2 class="mb-30"><a name="#distro">Distribución del espacio</a></h2>
      </div>`

Comment: @gamma please edit the question. The code in the comment is unreadable

Comment: See edit on my answer.

Comment: Sorry, newbie here. Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will open the page `servicios.html` and then go to the anchor `#distro`:

```
<li>
  <a href="servicios.html#distro">Distribución del espacio</a>
</li>
```

This will go straight to the anchor:

```
<li>
     <a href="#distro">Distribución del espacio</a>
</li>
```

Make sure you only have one id `distro`

```
<section id="distro" ... >
```

You can also try:

```
 <section name="distro" ... >
```

But the browser will first look for the id and then the name. 
[HTML Anchors with 'name' or 'id'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id)

Comment: Interesting, I will try that! Will keep you posted!

Comment: Perfect, please upvote if it worked, I see you already accepted as the best answer, thanks. Any questions, leave them here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#distro">Distribución del espacio</a>

<section id="distro" class="section-block replicable-content bkg-charcoal color-white no-padding-bottom">
  <div class="row horizon" data-animate-in="preset:slideInRightShort;duration:1000ms;" data-threshold="0.3">
    <div class="column width-5 offset-2">
      <h2 class="mb-30"><a href="#distro">Distribución del espacio</a></h2>
    </div>
  ...
```

You need to use `href` on the anchor, not `name`. And if the target is on the same page, you do not need to name the whole file in `href`, just the fragment starting with the hash sign.

Comment: That's exactly what am using. If I use div ID's, it only works on the first clicked item, but then in the second a blank page appears. Using good ol' anchors behave like this too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for all your kind responses. Turns out the key to this puzzle was that some sections were not defined as such but as only as divs. By making all of them separate sections, I got everything to work as needed.

Appreciate your support!